# Crop WPF control

Tags: wpf, crop

I have to crop some control to show only a half of it but the rest should be transparent and clickable so it is not enough to cover the control with something. The result should give a control with only half of the content (for example 50% of top) and the rest should be cropped (not hidden) so some other control below should be visible and not overlapped by cropped part. New control should also scale when window is scaled. How to do this in WPF?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have finally did the trick using Border around the control and Clip property of this border was set to Multibinging that was generating Rectangle basing on ActualWidth and ActualHeight of my control

Answer (score -2):

Maybe GridSplitter:

http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/panels/gridsplitter/

Can be used to split views horizontally/vertically, and can be responsive.

Comment: It is not what I'm looking for - I have added image to orginal post

Comment: You mean Grid? Wrapping them both with Grid?

Comment: There is no grid and gridsplitter is not helping. Cropping that I'm loking for should cut the content of the control and display always the upper part of it. Grid is responsible to layout elements and not to cut them.

Comment: Maybe OpacityMask on the top control?

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743320(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I have tried this but controls that have mouse over are still activated even when I hover over transparent area